# RPM packaging - requires not working as expected

Tags: rpm, packaging, rpmbuild, rpm-spec

I'm building an rpm, I have a few requirements, a few of them aren't really working:
Here's what I'm writing in the spec file:

```
Requires    : java-1.8.0-openjdk = 1.8.0.65-3.b17.el7
Requires    : apache-tomcat = 8.0.24-8.el7
Requires    : postgresql-server = 9.2.14-1.el7_1
Requires    : PyGreSQL = 4.0-9.el7
Requires    : systemd-units
Requires    : logrotate = 3.8.6-6.el7
Requires    : influxdb = 0.9.4.2-6
Requires    : kafka = 0.8.2.0-6.el7
Requires    : curl = curl-7.29.0-25.el7
Requires    : python-iptools = 0.6.1-1.el7
Requires    : shadow-utils = 4.1.5.1-18.el7
```

When I'm trying to install the rpm using the following command:

```
yum --nogpgcheck localinstall $myrpm
```

I'm getting the following errors:

```
Error: Package: $myrpm (/$myrpm)
           Requires: curl = curl-7.29.0-25.el7
           Installed: curl-7.29.0-25.el7.x86_64 (@anaconda/7.1)
               curl = 7.29.0-25.el7
           Available: curl-7.29.0-19.el7.x86_64 (rhel-7-1-base)
               curl = 7.29.0-19.el7
Error: Package: $myrpm (/$myrpm)
           Requires: java-1.8.0-openjdk = 1.8.0.65-3.b17.el7
           Available: 1:java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.31-1.b13.el7.centos.x86_64 (pd-3rdparty)
               java-1.8.0-openjdk = 1:1.8.0.31-1.b13.el7.centos
           Available: 1:java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.31-2.b13.el7.x86_64 (rhel-7-1-base)
               java-1.8.0-openjdk = 1:1.8.0.31-2.b13.el7
           Available: 1:java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.45-30.b13.el7_1.x86_64 (pd-3rdparty)
               java-1.8.0-openjdk = 1:1.8.0.45-30.b13.el7_1
           Available: 1:java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.65-3.b17.el7.x86_64 (rhel-7-server-rpms)
               java-1.8.0-openjdk = 1:1.8.0.65-3.b17.el7
Error: Package: $myrpm (/$myrpm)
           Requires: shadow-utils = 4.1.5.1-18.el7
           Installed: 2:shadow-utils-4.1.5.1-18.el7.x86_64 (@anaconda/7.1)
               shadow-utils = 2:4.1.5.1-18.el7
```

Output from `rpm -qpR $myrpm`

```
/bin/bash
/bin/sh
/bin/sh
/bin/sh
/bin/sh
/bin/sh
/usr/bin/env
/usr/bin/python
PyGreSQL = 4.0-9.el7
apache-tomcat = 8.0.24-8.el7
config(pd-sys-mgmt) = 1.0.837-cobradrop1.801b7ff8+
curl = curl-7.29.0-25.el7
influxdb = 0.9.4.2-6
java-1.8.0-openjdk = 1.8.0.65-3.b17.el7
kafka = 0.8.2.0-6.el7
logrotate = 3.8.6-6.el7
osgi(org.eclipse.persistence.core)
postgresql-server = 9.2.14-1.el7_1
python-iptools = 0.6.1-1.el7
rpmlib(CompressedFileNames) <= 3.0.4-1
rpmlib(FileDigests) <= 4.6.0-1
rpmlib(PartialHardlinkSets) <= 4.0.4-1
rpmlib(PayloadFilesHavePrefix) <= 4.0-1
shadow-utils = 4.1.5.1-18.el7
systemd-units
rpmlib(PayloadIsXz) <= 5.2-1
```

Answer (score 2):

I believe your `curl = curl-7.29.0-25.el7` entry shouldn't have `curl` on the right-hand side. It isn't part of the version string.

Your `java-1.8.0-openjdk` requirement appears to be missing the leading epoch value `1` (see `1:1.8.0.65-3.b17.el7` in the yum output). (Though I'm a bit surprised if you actually need to include that.)

Similarly `shawdow-utils` appears to be missing the leading `2` epoch (see `2:4.1.5.1-18.el7` in the yum output).

That all said being so *incredibly* specific in your requirements is likely a bad idea. It means you won't be able to update any of those packages while your package is installed (without rebuilding it) even if, as is likely, whatever you are packaging would work with updated versions just fine.